# Element is not in response Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I would to scrape the last odds in archive from this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/estonia/esiliiga/elva-flora-tallinn/Q9KlbwaJ/ but I can't get it with requests. How can I get it without interact with `Selenium`?
To trigger the archive odds page in the Developer Tools I need to hover on the odd.
[image]

[image]

Code

```
 url = "https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/4l4ubxv464x0xc78lr/14/"
 headers = {
            "Referer": "https://www.betexplorer.com",
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
               }
Json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: Your code gives me the JSON data. What issue do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

As the site is being loaded by JavaScript, `requests` doesn't work. I have used `selenium` to load the page, extract the complete source code after everything is loaded.

Then used `beautifulsoup` to create a `soup` object to get required data.

From the source code you can see that the `data-bid` of the `<tr>` are what are being passed to get the `odds` data.

I extracted all the `data-bid` and passed them to the URL you've provided at the very end of your question one by one.

**This code will get all the odds data in JSON format**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

base_url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/estonia/esiliiga/elva-flora-tallinn/Q9KlbwaJ/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base_url)

time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
t = soup.find('table', attrs= {'id': 'sortable-1'})
trs = t.find('tbody').findAll('tr')

for i in trs:
    data_bid = i['data-bid']
    url = f"https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/4l4ubxv464x0xc78lr/{data_bid}/"
    headers = {"Referer": "https://www.betexplorer.com",'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}
    Json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    
    # Do what you wish to do withe JSON data here....
```

Comment: The issue still, in the response is missing the last element from archive

Comment: What last element ?

Comment: Check the first pic, the red element is missing in the response

Comment: **That element is not present in the JSON itself.** (*See your JSON screenshot in your question*). You cannot get something that doesn't exist.